# Splitting complex punctuated strings into regular words greater than 2 character with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, split, cpu-word

As the title suggests:

I'm trying to split sentences into either a comma-separated string or array consisting of sanitized words greater than 2 characters in length and unique (duplicates removed).

An example string might be:

```
$sString = 'Stackoverflow's users are awesome!!! Stackoverflow, is the "best" technical questions and answers website on the interwebnet!';
```

Finished article:

```
$sStringAfterProcessing = 'stackoverflow, users, are, awesome, the, best, technical, questions, and, answers, website, interwebnet';
```

Note the first stackflow has the 's removed, punctuation and duplicates are removed.

This seems like it could get very complicated.

Suggestions welcome and all help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here goes...

```
str = str.replace(/[^\w\s]/ig, "").replace(/\s/g, ", ");
```

will yield:

> Stackoverflows, users, are, awesome, Stackoverflow, is, the, best, technical, questions, and, answers, website, on, the, interwebnet

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ktFj2/1/

Or, in array format:

```
var arr = str.replace(/[^\w\s]/ig, "").split(" ");
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/nnKV8/

**Update:** To remove duplicates from the array (and items with length `< 2`), something like this:

```
var cleaned = [];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var el = arr[i];

    if (el.length > 2 && $.inArray(el, cleaned) < 0) {
        cleaned.push(el);
    }
}
```

Comment: What would be the best way to remove duplicates after this process?

Comment: @Haraldo: Ah! I forgot that requirement. I'll add something that removes duplicates.

Comment: I was trying the jQuery $.merge function but id didn't seem to work - have you looked at merge as an option to remove duplicates?

Comment: Still having trouble with some punctuation. certain words such as "news:" or "news'" etc. (ignore quotes) get through. Whats the best way to remove these annoyances? Extra regex parameters?

Comment: Really? The RegExp should be removing all non word characters. What browser are you in?

Comment: Firefox - Its odd, so I went with - sText.replace(/[^\w\s{2,}.]/g, '').replace(/[!"£$%^&*()_\-=+{}\[\]~#@':;<,>?\/¬`´|\\]/g, '').toLowerCase()

Comment: I'm in firefox too and not seeing any problems... Weird, the regex is fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic way(edited):

```
    var s = 'Stackoverflow\'s users are awesome!!! Stackoverflow, is the "best" technical questions and answers website on the interwebnet!',
    a = s.split(/[^\w]/),
    h = {},
    l = a.length,
    i = 0,
    f = [];
    for(; i < l; i++){
        if(!h[a[i]] && a[i].length > 2){
            h[a[i]] = true;
            f.push(a[i]);
        }
    }
    console.log(f);
```

Comment: @Haraldo, I edited the answer to provide an array of words instead of a hash

Answer (score 0):

```
var newStrings = str.split(/[\\ \\.\\,]/);
```

Put any other punctuation in the regex, or use \W for non-alphanumeric characters.

This will yield an array of actual words in str.

Then, iterate through newStrings and print only the elements whose length >= 2!